# Order by function in Solr.NET

Tags: solrnet

How can I order result set by function?

I would like order by

```
query({!dismax qf=ProfessionName v='"data scientist"~3'}) desc, SaveDate desc
```

SortOrder should use only for fields.

Comment: `new SortOrder("query({!dismax qf=ProfessionName v='\"data scientist\"~3'})", Order.DESC)`

Comment: I'm getting InvalidSortOrderException. We using nuget package and I see that nuget package is so old. Thanks!

Comment: yes, always check https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/README.md#downloads

Comment: Are you going to update nuget package some day or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use SolrNet from github. SolrNet on Nuget was updated some years ago.